# How to format specific words in a sentence in react-intl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

How to render nested elements in `react-intl`

What I'm trying to render:

```
<FormattedMessage>
    This is a <strong>House</strong>
</FormattedMessage>
```

This has been discussed here and [there](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/513#issuecomment-252114827) should be examples in the docs, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 10):

What you want is called [Rich Text Formatting](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components/#rich-text-formatting). Here is an example:

```json
{
  "SENTENCE_WITH_BOLD_WORDS": "This is a <b>house</b>"
}
```

```js
<FormattedMessage
  id="SENTENCE_WITH_BOLD_WORDS"
  values={{
    b: (chunks) => <strong style={{ color: "red" }}>{chunks}</strong>
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64122522/react-intl-how-to-add-a-number-in-a-message (forked)]